# Regarding Servlet and JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I was practicing Servlet and JSP and got stuck with an scenario

this is my html page code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Second.jsp" method="post">
        <p>Name:<input type="text" name="name"/>
        <p>Employee Id:<input type="text" name="empId" />
        <p><input type="submit" value="Enter" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JSP Code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <jsp:useBean id="person" class="com.Person" scope="request">
        <jsp:setProperty name="person" property="name" />
    </jsp:useBean>
    <jsp:getProperty property="name" name="person"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Person.java

```
package com;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My request goes directly to jsp and the form element name and bean property name matches so no need tp set value in jsp:setProperty

However getProperty is showing null.

Comment: I pulled your example into eclipse and everything was working fine.

Comment: for me its showing null

Comment: any idea why its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Within the second page simply use:

`${param.name}` and `${param.empId}`

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `param` attribute.

```
<jsp:useBean id="person" class="com.Person" scope="request">
    <jsp:setProperty name="person" property="name" param="name" />
</jsp:useBean>
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="name"/> and java bean property name is also "name" so i dont think param attribute is required

Comment: Yeah, you're correct. Since, the names match the attribute isn't required. Have you shared your exact code 'coz there's nothing that seems wrong about it.